# IfElse checking if scan equals to IPv4

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I would like to know, how to make If-statement check, if `myClientMachineIp` (from the code) equals to `AddressFamily.InterNetwork`?

My current code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim myClientMachineAddressList As IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName())
        Dim myClientMachineIP As String = myClientMachineAddressList.AddressList(0).ToString()

        If myClientMachineIP = AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
            TextBox1.Text = myClientMachineIP
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = "IP does not equal to IPv4"

        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't throw away valuable information by calling `ToString()`. Use the `IPAddress` type:

```
Dim myClientMachineAddressList _
    = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName())
Dim myClientMachineIP = myClientMachineAddressList.AddressList(0)

If myClientMachineIP.AddressFamily = Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
    TextBox1.Text = myClientMachineIP.ToString()
Else
    TextBox1.Text = "IP does not equal to IPv4".
End If
```

Comment: How to output that myClientMachineIP to textbox?